# Spring dependency injection in Security.Authenticator

Tags: spring, playframework

I have written a custom authenticator for my Play 2.3.4 application which has spring dependency injection configured. I want to be able to inject an 'authService' into my authenticator, but this is not working. My authService is always null. Is it possible to configure autowired injection into authenticators? My authenticator is as follows:

```
package controllers;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
public class AppAuthenticator extends Security.Authenticator {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authService")
    private AuthService authService;

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
      ...
      authService.getAuthenticatedUser();
      ...
    }

    public void setAuthService(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    ...

}
```

And my Spring configuration includes:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>
<bean id="authService" class="com.my.auth.class.AuthServiceClass" />
<bean class="play.mvc.Security$AuthenticatedAction" scope="prototype" />
```

In summary, spring doesn't seem to be injecting properties into my Sercuirty.Authenticator. How do you configure this correctly?